# Regex to find instances of String.Compare with two parameters

Tags: c#, regex, notepad++

I'm looking for instances in my code where I have forgotten to include a 'true' for the third parameter, which lets it be case insensitive.

The code would either look like `String.Compare("stringA", varB)` or `String.Compare(varA, "stringB", true)` and I would want to use regex to find all instances of cases where I only have used two parameters.

So far I came up with this: `String.Compare\([^,\n]*((,[^,\n]*?))\)`, which works for simple cases but I'm not sure how to deal with things such as if the parameter has a `.ToString()` at the end of it.

If anybody has any advice to how I could improve my regex or even a completely different but more efficient solution to my issue that would be great!

**EDIT:** Just wanted to mention that sometimes it could broken up into different lines:

```
if (String.Compare(varA.ToString(),
varB.ToString().Trim(),
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
```

Comment: Visual Studio, right-click on `String.Compare`, and click "Find all references?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is a one-time task I would do it with Notepad++ in several steps.

1. Mark all lines containing `String.Compare`. Use "Mark" tab of Find and replace dialogue, ensure "Bookmark line" is ticked.
2. Inverse bookmarks. Use menu => Search => Bookmarks => Inverse bookmarks. Now all lines that do NOT contain `String.Compare` are marked.
3. Do a mark lines with the regular expression `String\.Compare\([^,\n]*,[^,\n]*, *true\);$`. This add marks on the string compare lines that have the wanted `true`. Note the final `;$` in the regular expression. It ensures that the `true` is indeed the third parameter of the call and is not matching a `true` earlier in the line. This does not need anything extra for the `\.ToString()` clauses
4. Inverse bookmarks.
5. Now have marks on all the `String.Compare` lines that do not have the wanted `true` as the third parameter on the line.

To summarise: Find (and mark) the lines that are OK, then inverse the marks to highlight the lines that may need attention.

In response to the changed question, change the regular expression in step-3 to be
`String\.Compare\([^,]*,[^,]*,\s*true\)(\s*!=\s*0\))?$`
or even 
`String\.Compare\([^,]*,[^,]*,\s*StringComparison\.\w+\)(\s*!=\s*0\))?$`.

This change allows for the third parameter to be a `StringComparison` enumeration and also for the comparison result to be compared against zero.

Changing the regular expression to `String\.Compare\([^,]*,[^,]*,\s*(true|StringComparison\.\w+)\)(\s*!=\s*0\))?$` should allow either `true` or a `StringComparison` enumeration as the third parameter. Generally I am against using such complex regular expressions. They get difficult to understand and difficult to enhance. For a task such as in this question and the style of solution given in this answer it may be better to perform two or more mark lines operations with different expressions at step-3 above.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering, what would be a Regex for a general third term? One that could include both "true" and "StringComparison"? This is helpful for dealing with code that has been written by many developers.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few things to improve. If you don't need the capturing groups you can omit them turning them into non capturing `(?:`. There is also a double capturing group `((` where you could omit the outer one.

You can escape the dot after `String.` or else it would match any char except a newline.

In your negated character class you match not a `,` or `\n`, but if there can not be a closing parenthesis you might also add that to it like `[^,\n)]`.

You could also remove the question mark after `[^,\n]*?` which will make it non greedy.

Your expression might look like:

```
String\.Compare\([^,\n)]*(?:,[^,\n)]*)\)
```

If you want to match all non whitespace chars that follow starting with a dot, you  could add an optional non capturing group:

```
String\.Compare\([^,\n)]*(?:,[^,\n)]*)\)(?:\.\S+)?
```

If String should not be part of a larger word, you might prepend a word boundary `\bString`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdKE0G/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and don't remember to ignore case:

```
String\.Compare\([^,]*(?:,[^,()]*)(\(\))?\);$
```